# Upload File to OpenStack Using Python Swift Client

Tags: python, swift, upload, openstack

Would someone have a complete example of how to upload a file to an OpenStack container using the Python Swift client: https://pypi.org/project/python-swiftclient/

Something that would include:

- Authenticate against the OpenStack instance
- Call the relevant function(s) to upload the file to an OpenStack container

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the following piece of code

```py
from keystoneauth1 import session
from keystoneauth1.identity import v3
from swiftclient.client import Connection

# Create a password auth plugin
auth = v3.Password(
    auth_url='https://cloud.company.com:5000/v3/',
    username='myaccount',
    password='mypassword',
    user_domain_name='Default',
    project_name='myproject',
    project_domain_name='Default'
)

# Create session
keystone_session = session.Session(auth=auth)

# Create swiftclient Connection
swift_conn = Connection(session=keystone_session)

# Create container
swift_conn.put_container('test')

# Read file
with open('myfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    file_data = f.read()

# Upload file
swift_conn.put_object('test', 'myfile.txt', file_data)
```